# f:param is not working with h:graphicImage

Tags: jsf-2

I'm getting `<f:param>` i.e., `menuItemIndex` value as `null` during my ajax call. Is it because it is with in `<h:graphicImage>` ??? Can any one suggest please? Note: Parameter is getting passed if I use `<h:commandLink>` instead of `<h:graphicImage>`.

```
 <c:forEach items="#{cc.attrs.value}" var="menuItem" varStatus="loopItem">
 ....
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{menuItem.hasChildren}">
        <h:graphicImage library="images" name="#{menuItem.symbol}">
           <f:ajax render=":fatcaForm:myMenu:menuID" event="click" listener="#{menuBean.refreshMenu}" />
           <f:param name="menuItemIndex" value="{loopItem.count}" />
        </h:graphicImage>
    </ui:fragment>
  ....
 </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h:graphicImage>` is not a command component and it does therefore not support `<f:param>` children at all. The `<f:param>` works only when nested in an `UICommand` component, such as `<h:commandLink>` as you found out yourself.

So, this should do:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{menuBean.refreshMenu}">
    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="#{menuItem.symbol}" />
    <f:ajax render=":fatcaForm:myMenu:menuID" />
    <f:param name="menuItemIndex" value="#{loopItem.count}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

*(note that I fixed the EL syntax error in the `<f:param value>` as well)*

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, how you used the `<h:graphicImage library>` is not entirely right. Please carefully read [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: Thx a lot but my image is getting placed inside a square BORDER when using your code (i.e., `<h:graphicImage>` inside `<h:commandLink>`). how to get rid of it? functionality is working though.

Comment: That's just a styling matter. Just add `a img { border: 0; }` to CSS.